# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have done this tutorial and it crashes while running. I tried with the downloaded the code for the tutorial and it also crashes. The code from the tutorial is complete.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/ejb3/ejb-tutorial-beginners/

I  have used

- NetBeans version 8.1
- Glassfish 4.1.1
- JDK 1.7
- Windows 8.1

I can build and run, fill in two strings in the Servlet.

Then after clicking "Create" I get this:
[Image of the error, in the web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47slL.png)

The complete error message:

```
type Exception report
messageInternal Server Error
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController
root cause
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController
root cause
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController/accountService,Remote 3.x interface =com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote,refType=Session into class com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController/accountService' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
root cause
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController/accountService' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController/accountService,Remote 3.x interface =com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote not found]]]
root cause
javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.javacodegeeks.example.tester.AccountController/accountService,Remote 3.x interface =com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote not found]]
root cause
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote not found]
root cause
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote#com.javacodegeeks.example.service.AccountServiceRemote not found
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
```

Comment: Whether the JDK version is related to this particular exception or not but  JDK 8u60 or above is recommended for GlassFish Server 4.1.1.

Comment: Tried that, still get the same exact error message.